# How to limit email lookup fields to account contacts while sending email from account in Lightning?

Tags: email, lightning-experience, activities

While sending an email from an account in Lightning using the standard Activities email component, the address lookup appears to first pull matching users ("Bob" in my example) from account contacts, then pull other contacts from other sources, including other accounts. If we don't have any account contacts, it will just pull from other sources:

[image: Bob]

It's easy to see how this could be a problem if you accidentally select a "Bob" from the wrong account and send him sensitive information about your intended "Bob".

Is there a way to limit this component to just show contacts related to the account you are sending from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear so in Lightning as I experience the same functionality you are seeing on accounts. This was in the [Winter 20 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_cases_lookup_contacts.htm) where it seems to give what you're asking for, but only on the email publisher on Cases in Service Console.

Looking at the documentation for [sending an email from a record in Lightning](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=send_email_directly_from_crm_record.htm&type=5), it doesn't seem to specify that a given contact or lead needs to be related to the object you're on. **Considering this is an out of the box functionality, I don't think it's likely you'll have an ability to filter what results display in the To Address**.

[image]